# Index/Match values from a column using a grid of a different length (Excel 2010)

Tags: excel

I am trying to index match values from a long column to a grid of a different length.  It looks like this

```
 Word         Number      Column X     Column Y   Column Z   
 This          55          55           33          12
 is            62          62           42          18
 The           78          78           31          24
               42 
               31
               12
               18
               24
               33
```

The grid (Column X,Y,Z) contains all the values from the Number Column.  **What I am trying to do is basically index the "Word" column, using a value from the "Number" Column, and looking it up in the value array of X Y Z.**

Example (because this is confusing):

Input the Value 33 from the Number column, look for the value in the columns XYZ, and then return the Word "This".

Input the Value 18 from the number column, look for the value in columns XYZ, return the word "is"

etc...

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Where are you planning on returning the result?

Comment: To clarify, will an input of 55, 33 or 12 return (expected) "This"? Same for [62,42,18] -> "is", etc.?

Comment: @electrycalaj yes that is exactly right

Comment: This is not the same question pnuts

Comment: I posted a solution for you based on your response. You spelled my name wrong btw :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a quicker way and shorter formula to do this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,IFERROR(MATCH(B2,C:C,0),IFERROR(MATCH(B2,D:D,0),MATCH(B2,E:E,0))),1),"not found")
```

paste that into, any column really, into row 2 and drag down, it will return the words you require, if value not found it will return "not found"

Answer (score 1):

Here is your spreadsheet starting at cell **A1** (without your headers):

```
        A       B       C       D       E
1     This      55      55      33      12
2     is        62      62      42      18
3     The       78      45      31      24
4               42                      
5               31                      
6               12                      
7               18                      
8               24                      
9               33                      
10                                      
11    Input:    24                      
12    Output:   The
```

Copy this into cell **C10**, and drag the formula across to cell **E10**:

```
=IF(ISERROR(IF(ISERROR(IF(ISERROR(MATCH($B$11,C1:C3,0)),"",CONCATENATE("A",MATCH($B$11,C1:C3,0)))),"",INDIRECT(IF(ISERROR(MATCH($B$11,C1:C3,0)),"",CONCATENATE("A",MATCH($B$11,C1:C3,0)))))),"",IF(ISERROR(IF(ISERROR(MATCH($B$11,C1:C3,0)),"",CONCATENATE("A",MATCH($B$11,C1:C3,0)))),"",INDIRECT(IF(ISERROR(MATCH($B$11,C1:C3,0)),"",CONCATENATE("A",MATCH($B$11,C1:C3,0))))))
```

Copy this to the "output" cell **B12** and use cell **B11** as your "input":

```
=CONCATENATE(C10,D10,E10)
```

*VIOLA!!!* You're done!

### Proof:

The `MATCH()` function will look for your value in an array (the range). If it finds it, it returns the index of that array (indexed at 1), otherwise it throws an error. Be sure to set the 3rd argument to "0" so that it only looks for EXACT matches. 
Paste this into **C14**:

```
=MATCH($B$11,C1:C3,0)
```

Next, we check if the `MATCH()` function did indeed throw an error. Paste this into **C15**:

```
=IF(ISERROR(C14),"",C14)
```

Now we have the *row number* of our matched value, so we will use the `CONCATENATE()` function to join it to our "word column", **A**, for use in the next step. Paste this into **C16**:

```
 =CONCATENATE("A",C15)
```

Using that *string* from above, use the `INDIRECT()` function to turn it into an actual cell reference. Paste this into **C17**:

```
=INDIRECT(C16)
```

And finally, check if a legitimate cell reference was created. If so, return the *word*, otherwise return "". Paste this into **C18**:

```
=IF(ISERROR(C17),"",C17)
```

Lastly, drag the formulas from **C14:C18** to **E14:E18**, and concatenate the results. The cells in row **18** should match the cells in row **10**.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, this works but I tend to stay from the indirect function because i have a ton of data to work with.  Thank you so much though!